# How to run successfully Protractor e2e test in Cloud Builders?

Tags: selenium, docker, google-cloud-platform, protractor, continuous-integration

I'm setting up CI for our project that is in Angular. We are using Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Builder for CI. Everything is going smoothly, we can setup the environment, install packages via `npm`, build the project using `angular-cli` and deploy. But the problem is that our test cases (e2e) in Protractor keeps getting an error. What are we missing here?

This is for the Continuous Integration using Google Cloud Builders, we are running the protractor in headless mode, and using the puppeteer's chromium as the chrome's binary path

This is my protractor.conf.js

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath()

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 1000000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/*.e2e-spec.ts',
    '../e2e/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    // browserName: 'chrome',
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    }
  },
  // seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  // ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
  directConnect: true,
  },
};
```

This is the error we are getting in cloud builders

```
[11:24:12] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-662092/chrome-linux/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1033-gcp x86_64)
[11:24:12] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-662092/chrome-linux/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: It may be because of the chrome version.

Comment: When executing locally is protractor installed globally or locally in project?

Comment: when executing locally, I am using the protractor inside my project. I also tried to use it globally with success. I am having this trouble when I tried to run it in CI

Comment: Hey, I am also in the same boat, facing the same exception. Did you manage to get any working solution, yet?

Comment: apparently not yet

Comment: @LalitNarayanMishra did you solve this?